# Using jQuery to disable a button after submit does not pass the value of the button

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a really strange issue that is bugging me. I have two forms that disable the submit button once it's clicked to prevent a form from sending a duplicate value.

Example One (Working)

```
 <script>
                  $('#addposition').submit(function(){
                      $('#SavePosition').val('Saving...');
                      $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  });
            </script> 
             <script>
                  $('#addposition').submit(function(){
                      $('#saveandedit').val('Saving...');
                      $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  });
            </script>
```

Here are the submit buttons used in this positions form.

```
<input type="submit" id="SavePosition" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit & Add Position">
<input type="submit" id="saveandedit" class="btn btn-info" name="SaveAndEdit" value="Submit & Edit New Position">
```

There are 2 buttons on the screen, depending on what the user clicks, will determine what code is run and what page is shown next.

When this is executed, I can determine on the existence of #saveandedit  if I am sending the user to the save and edit page. The page that the form is submitted to, will process the form variables. If #saveandedit is not there, then they go to the save and add page.

Example Two (Not Working)

```
                <script>
              $('#addcandidate').submit(function(){
                  $('#saveandedit').val('Submitting...');
                  $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              });
            </script>
             <script>
              $('#addcandidate').submit(function(){
                  $('#saveandadd').val('Submitting...');
                  $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              });
            </script>
```

Here are the buttons for this candidate form

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="saveandedit" name="saveandedit" value="Submit & Edit New Candidate">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveandadd" name="saveandadd" value="Submit & Add New Candidate">
```

The same should be true here. If the #saveandedit exists on the processing page, then we send the user the save and edit page. However, there is no #saveandedit variable period. I can look at the whole variable scope and that value is not present.

I have looked at the URL that is posted to the processing page and for the candidates page, there is no value for save and edit.

However, on the positions page, I can clearly see the value for Save and edit and that page works properly.

Is there any reason why using this simple snip of jQuery code would kill that button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled form elements are not submitted, this is part of the [HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set).

As a workaround, you could add a hidden input field and assign a value to it, depending on which button has been clicked.

Example that works for me:

```
<form method="post" id="addcandidate">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="saveandedit" name="saveandedit" value="Submit & Edit New Candidate">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveandadd" name="saveandadd" value="Submit & Add New Candidate">
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value=""/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#saveandedit').click(function(){
    $('#action').val('saveandedit');
});

$('#saveandadd').click(function(){
    $('#action').val('saveandadd');
});

$('#addcandidate').submit(function(){
    $('#addcandidate input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true).val('Submitting...');
});
```

[Fiddle (similar)](http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/94psybas/)

Comment: I thought of this as well but when I added a hidden field and tried to assign a value it didn't work. It was not submitted. I was thinking that something weird was going on but why would it work for the value listed above?? Anyway, I'm more than happy to use a hidden field but the way I tried which was to assign the value within the javasctipt didn't work. Also, should that value of assignment happen before the ('Submitting...') line?

Comment: I added an example and Fiddle, both worked for me. The order should not matter, afaik the submit handlers are processed before the form is actually submitted.

Comment: Thanks I just double checked the order and tested adding a value of 1 for true and 0 for false. I now can catch this on the processing page. This will work. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

For second example your submit button id is different then jquery hence it will not work.

Comment: your submit button ids are "saveandedit" and "saveandadd" but in your second jquery you are using "addcandidate" to submit

Comment: one more thing you should wrap your jquery code in $(function(){ your code
});

Comment: "saveandedit" and "saveandadd" are the IDs of the buttons, "addcandidate" is the ID of the form that wraps those buttons.

Comment: ohhh my bad  i missed its submit function not click

Comment: No worries, yes they have different names to determine which button was clicked on the processing page.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS for the button to appear disabled and a javascript preventDefault() should do the trick.